# How to override formatting of a specific part of highlighted code block in markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, markup

I want to use code block in markdown with enabled code highlighting. At the same time, I often want to override formatting for some part of that block to pay attention to it.
For example, I have this markup:

````
```bash
var="Hello World"
# print it 
echo "$var"
# Another way of printing it
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```
````

which gives me this highlighting:

```bash
var="Hello World"
# print it 
echo "$var"
# Another way of printing it
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

Now, let's say I want to pay attention to this `%s` thing. I want to make it bold (or make red color, or make another background color, does not matter).

But I cannot see such possibility. There are similar questions, for example [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183610). But my question does not accept that highlighting will be lost. I want to preserve it.

I even would be happy to see any hacky way, maybe something like this:

```
<pre>
<code class="language-bash">var="Hello World"
# print it 
echo "$var"
# Another way of printing it
printf "</code></pre>**%s**<pre><code class="language-bash">\n" "$var"
</code></pre>
```

but it does not work unfortunately.

Maybe there is a way to apply the highlighting to the random piece of text? I mean, without needing to make it in block, because that prohibits me to write further on the same line (i.e. that `%s` is on next line).

Maybe markdown should be extended to support overriding like this:

````
```bash
var="Hello World"
# print it 
echo "$var"
# Another way of printing it
printf "```**%s**```\n" "$var"
```
````

Currently it is just ignored:

````bash
var="Hello World"
# print it 
echo "$var"
# Another way of printing it
printf "```**%s**```\n" "$var"
````

Answer (score 0):

In Markdown, code blocks are typically used to display code snippets without any additional formatting. The syntax highlighting is applied automatically based on the language specified after the opening code fence (e.g., "```bash"). Markdown itself does not provide a way to selectively override formatting within a code block while preserving syntax highlighting.

If you need to highlight a specific portion of the code block without losing the syntax highlighting, you can use a combination of inline HTML and CSS. Here's an example:

```bash
var="Hello World"
# print it 
echo "$var"
# Another way of printing it
printf "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>%s</span>\n" "$var"
```

In this example, we wrap the `%s` part within a `<span>` element and apply the CSS style `font-weight: bold;` to make it bold. You can modify the CSS style as per your needs, such as changing the color or background.

Please note that the effectiveness of this approach depends on the rendering engine used for displaying the Markdown, as different platforms may handle HTML and CSS differently. It's a good practice to test your Markdown on the specific platform or tool you're using to ensure the desired formatting is preserved.

Comment: But in that example the span tag is written as is. Does it work anywhere? I want to use the overriding in gitlab, github, mediawiki, and here in stackexchange sites.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT